# PubNub UUID showing different results in dashboard

Tags: pubnub

We implemented PubNub and we set UUID. Yesterday I tested it. I used only 2 iPhones, but here are 15 Daily Active Devices and around 16 Peak UUIDs. We hardcoded UUID for our 2 iPhones "iPhone4S" and "iPhone5C", but still Daily Active Devices and Peak UUIDs were showing 10+.

Can someone help us with this. We even compared with PubNub's demo app and it's the same. I don't know why is this happening, why we have Peak UUIDs showing 10+ when we hardcoded 2 values.

Comment: Sure, this is the day we hardcoded http://i.imgsafe.org/1e7ae1a.png
It's showing 10 UUIDs. For example day after 25 Feb, we had 64 UUIDs with 2 iPhone, that's when were removed hardcoded values

Comment: We are using iOS SDK and PHP SDK on local Croatian shared hosting. PHP SDK is used only for publishing messages to specific channel. We are having problem with iOS and UUID

Comment: Ahaaa, so I have to do it on server side also. I will. thanks, I think it will solve a problem :D

Comment: It worked, that's where I made a mistake

Comment: I removed all my comment in favor of an official answer. Please accept as official answer if you find it acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PubNub UUID - Create, Set, Store, Get & Reuse

For accurate active device counting and tracking, PubNub uses unique IP addresses by default. However, a more accurate way to do this is with UUIDs.

With the exception of the [JavaScript SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) & [iOS SDK](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/pubnub-objective-c-sdk-v4) (as of this writing), [PubNub's SDKs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs) generate a new UUID with every initialization/instantiate of the PubNub. So you can end up with a client device or server process reporting several different UUIDs each day.

Many developers will generate, locally store and reuse a UUID for the client applications but forget to do this on the server side processes that use PubNub, as well.

For more details about UUID generate/store/reuse with PubNub, please read PubNub KB article [How Do I Set the UUID](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/138/how-do-i-set-the-uuid).

Comment: Let me just add: set UUID **EVERYWHERE** you initialize PubNub object like in PHP, iOS, Javascript, Android... and use the same UUID for all of them, for example User ID from database or User Email.

Comment: Just to clarify... each individual user/device should have their own specific UUID. Each server process should use its own specific UUID. Sharing the same UUID everywhere is misrepresentative of the number of users/devices my counting too few and can also make Presence *misbehave*.